# Xamarin Forms using Acr.UserDialogs library with windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, prompt, xamarin.forms

When using the acr.UserDialogs library by Allan Ritchie ([Available Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)) the windows Phone project throws an error as mention in detail in following Xamarin forum post. 
Did anyone else came across this? Does someone has a workaround/ fix or a suggestion I can try?

Thanks

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/105675/#Comment_105675

Comment: Hi, did you get an solution for it ? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: yes https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/5

Comment: seriously? this was the solution? use the latest version? I am using most latest version and it doesn work at all

Comment: Suggest open an issue on that GitHub only. Allen is quick with his replies.

Comment: It is already reported here. Owner claims that it will be fixed soon. https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/41